# How to create a function that works for all data types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I’m trying to create a Generic function in Kotlin that will multiply two values if they are integer or double or float but concat them if any of them is a string.

I tried with this:

```
fun <T> func_name(x : T, y : T) {
    when {
        x is Int && y is Int -> return x*y
        x is Double && y is Double -> return x*y
        x is Float && y is Float -> return x*y
        else -> return x.toString() + y.toString()
    }
}
```

However, this will not get compiled as I’m missing something here.

How should I proceed and change this?

Comment: Where is the return type? This is a `void` `fun` but you return things… You can make it compile by changing the first line to `fun <T> func_name(x: T, y: T): Any {` making it return `Any` type. However, that might not make it actually work as expected… And function names should not contain underscores, but that's not the problem here…

Comment: This is really not the sort of function you can write in practice, precisely because its type is so messy.

Comment: What would be the benefit of being able to declare this, over declaring 4 functions? Do you have a real-life example? Note that there is no code duplication when writing 4 functions - no more than with the `when` approach (every `+` is a different one anyway so it's not possible to deduplicate, they just look the same but are different). Using 4 functions has the big advantage that the compiler can tell you at compile time whether the function exists for a given pair of types (in cases where no general `else` exists).

Comment: There’s no use for it. It is just one practice application I’m trying to understand Generics and Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the magic of `reified`, you *can* do this, but it's ugly:

```
inline fun <reified T> add(first: T, second: T) = when (T::class) {
    Int::class -> first as Int * second as Int
    Float::class -> first as Float * second as Float
    String::class -> first as String + second as String
    else -> error("Unsupported type ${T::class}")
} as T
```

or alternatively, if you don't care that the return type is `Any`:

```
inline fun <reified T> add(first: T, second: T) = when (T::class) {
    Int::class -> first as Int * second as Int
    Float::class -> first as Float * second as Float
    else -> first.toString() + second.toString()
}
```

The casts are safe because you explicitly checked the type, but the compiler doesn't know that.

It would be much better to split the functions up and let the compiler choose the right one:

```
fun add(first: Int, second: Int) = first * second
fun add(first: Float, second: Float) = first * second
fun add(first: String, second: Any) = first + second.toString()
```