# How to create a generic function that accepts two parameters and based on their date type returns different result?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am trying to understand the concept of Generics and as an exercise, I want to create a Generic function in Kotlin which accepts two parameters and returns a value based on the data type of these two parameters.

- If both parameters are Integer or Double, I want to return a sum of these two Numbers.
- If any one of them is a String, then I want to a concatenated string of both the parameters with a space in between, and thus I'd have to convert the non-string value to string before concatenating.

For this, I have so far tried this:

```
fun <T, U> combine (x: T, y: U) {
    return when {
        x is String && y is String -> x + " " + y
        x is String && y !is String -> x + " " + y.toString()
        x !is String && y is String -> x.toString() + " " + y
        else -> x + y
    }
}
```

However, this results in type inference errors either on the function side or on the returned value side. If I add the return type as `Any`, then it results in an error I couldn't quite figure out. And if I use `:T?` then it is possible that the returned type is not exactly T.

Can you guide me in the right direction for this?

Note that this exercise is for my learning only. It may not be the best way to do it or may not have practical use. I am just newly learning Programming for the first time.

Comment: As we already explained in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77352595/8681), *you cannot do that*. The type system just doesn't work that way. A return type has to be determined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I got the case now.

Jorn's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77353111/10916136) is one way to do it.

Another way I could understand is to always return the result as a string and then work your way ahead.

Final function develops to be:

```
fun fun <T,U> add (x: T, y: U) : String? {
    return when {
        x is String && y is String -> x + " " + y
        x is String && y !is String -> x + " " + y.toString()
        x !is String && y is String -> x.toString() + " " + y
        x is Double && y is Double -> (x + y).toString()
        x is Double && y is Int -> (x + y).toString()
        x is Int && y is Double -> (x + y).toString()
        x  is Int && y is Int -> (x + y).toString()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

This way we can achieve the objectives of the question using a Generic Function.